# How to disable drop down when selecting one in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

could someone help me fix my code?
My problem is how to disable another drop box when selected one?
I am using PHP and JavaScript programming language.
I hope that  anyone can help me because it is very important.

Here's my code:

```
    <head>
           <script type = "text/javascript">
            function disableDrop(){
           if(frmMain.sltMain.options[1].selected){
                 frmMain.sltSecondary.disabled = true;
              }
              else{
                 frmMain.sltSecondary.disabled = false;
                }
              }
                   </script>
        </head>

         <form ID = "frmMain">

      <select ID = "sltMain" onchange = "disableDrop();">
         <option value = "onetime" selected>One-Time</option>
         <option value = "recurring">Recurring</option>
           </select>

         <select ID = "sltMain" onchange = "disableDrop();">
           <option value = "onetime">One-Time</option>
        <option value = "recurring" selected>Recurring</option>
         </select>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This  : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/359nb4xy/6/)

**HTML CODING :**

```
  <select ID = "sltMain" onchange = "disableDrop(this);">
     <option value = "onetime" selected>One-Time</option>
     <option value = "recurring">Recurring</option>
       </select>

     <select ID = "sltSecondary" onchange = "disableDrop1(this);">
       <option value = "onetime">One-Time</option>
    <option value = "recurring" selected>Recurring</option>
     </select>
         </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function disableDrop(elem) {

    if(elem.value == 'recurring'){

    document.getElementById('sltSecondary').disabled = true;
    }
    else{
     document.getElementById('sltSecondary').disabled = false;        
    }

}
function disableDrop1(elem) {


    if(elem.value == 'onetime'){

    document.getElementById('sltMain').disabled = true;
    }
    else{
     document.getElementById('sltMain').disabled = false;        
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Kio Rii...dont forgot to make my answer as solution (by tick right beside my answer)...

Comment: how to do that? @vrajesh

Answer (score 1):

whre is the "sltSecondary" ID ??

the second item has the same id i think you mean

```
     <form ID = "frmMain">

  <select ID = "sltMain" onchange = "disableDrop();">
     <option value = "onetime" selected>One-Time</option>
     <option value = "recurring">Recurring</option>
       </select>

     <select ID = "sltSecondary" onchange = "disableDrop();">
       <option value = "onetime">One-Time</option>
    <option value = "recurring" selected>Recurring</option>
     </select>
         </form>
```

Comment: how to fix that code? the output that i want is when i choose one from the two drop down, one of them will be disabled..